# Excel Referencing to a range using concatenate

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-formula, covariance

I am trying to reference two arrays using the following formula:

```
=COVAR(CONCATENATE("Returns!"&D27&":"&D28),CONCATENATE("Returns!"&D27&":"&D28))
```

Where, for example, cell D27 contains: `=ADDRESS($B$3,D$29)` which returns $C$6. Therefore in theory I should have a COVAR argument containing the right elements.

However the COVAR calculation instead gives me a #VALUE! error. Can I not use CONCATENATE for this? If not, what is the solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a valid cell reference from a text value you can use INDIRECT function, e.g.

`=COVAR(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Returns!"&D27&":"&D28)),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Returns!"&D27&":"&D28)))`

although it would probably be easier not to use D27 and D28 at all and use your original B3 and D29 values with INDEX, e.g. something like

`=INDEX(Returns!A1:Z100,B3,D29)` will give you the start cell of the range so you can combine two INDEXes, something like

`=INDEX(Returns!A1:Z100,B3,D29):INDEX(Returns!A1:Z100,cell,cell)`

You can use that range directly in a function like COVAR without needing INDIRECT

Comment: As a side note, it is not necessary to use both the CONCATENATE function and the ampersand ("&") operator together. So, CONCATENATE("Returns!",D27,":",D28) is a valid string concatenation, as is "Returns!"&D27&":"&D28.